# How to record the audio output on Raspbian?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, audio-recording

On my Raspberry Pi I am running some Python files, which produces sound (pygame). I want to record those sounds while they're played.

Those are the outputs of the listed devices of `arecord`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
```

I tried several options with `arecord` to record the played sounds, but it was not possible to capture the system sounds. Is this not possible at all or is there another solution?

Comment: Are you running Pulseaudio? If yes, there's a simpler solution. If not, how did you configure the loopback devices? Did you configure the Python files to use the other end of the loopback device for playback? Or alternatively, did you set this as `default` in your `.asoundrc`?

Comment: I used `modprobe snd_bcm2835` before playing the sounds via Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say, but assume you don't use Pulseaudio. Do

```
ps axu | grep pulse
```

to make sure you are *really* not running Pulseaudio. If you do, the following won't work.

Your `modprobe snd_bcm2835` didn't create the loopback device that's shown in the question. So somewhere you have a `modprobe snd-aloop`, either you did it and forgot about it, or it's in some configuration.

To verify, do both `aplay -l` and `arecord -l`, it should show two devices on card 1 in both cases.

Now let's test the loopback device works. Find a large WAV file (say, 'music.wav'), open two terminals and do

```
aplay -vv -D hw:1,0,0 music.wav
```

in one terminal, and after that

```
arecord -vv -D hw:1,1,0 -f S16_LE -r 44100 -c 2 /dev/null
```

in the other. The parameters must match whatever format your WAV file has. You should see a VU meter for `aplay` moving in sync with the VU meter for `arecord`.

Finally, tell your Python programs to use `hw:1,0,0` as sound output device, however your Python programs work and whatever information they need to do that.

Or make an `~/.asoundrc` (per Linux user) or `/etc/asound.conf` (systemwide) with entries like

```
pcm.!default { type hw card 1 } 
ctl.!default { type hw card 1 }
```

assuming that `snd-aloop` gets always loaded to card 1, and cross your finger that your Python programs use `default` as default output.

Then you can record from the other end of the loopback device as described above.

Note: This is a virtual "sound card", you won't hear any sounds played and recorded through this "card". If you want to listen and record at the same time, I'd really suggest to just run Pulseaudio, it makes that a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't figured it out, how to get it work for python, but the first test was successful :) Is it also possible to "clone" the audio output? Actually I want to hear the sound on the speakers and it should also be recorded.

Comment: I'm not sure how to "clone" output under ALSA into two devices. It *might* work with some `asoundrc` magic using the same IPC keys for plugin, but I'm too lazy to test. As I said: Install Pulseaudio, just record from the `monitor` output of your sink, done. Vastly easier to configure.